# Agregar Un QPolygon a un QScrollArea

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Quisiera saber si es posible agregar un `QPolygon` a un `QScrollArea`, ya que el poligono se crea con puntos especificos, no se si sea esto posible.

Para este caso mi intencion fue crea una cantidad de 10 poligonos en el `QMainWindow` y tulizando un ciclo for incrementado el valor de su posision en `y` para poder generar una especie de lista, pero quisiera saber si es posible poder integrarlo en un   `QScrollArea`:

Esto es lo que trate de hacer:

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("testUI.ui",self)


        def paintEvent(self,event):

            painter = QPainter(self)

            self.other(painter)
            painter.end()

        def other(self,painter):
            central = QWidget()
            boxlayout  = QVBoxLayout(central)
            boxlayout.addStretch()
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black,1,Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green,Qt.SolidPattern))

            a = 10
            b = 10
            c = 50
            d = 50
            e = 60
            f = 50
            g = 50

            for i in range(10):

                points = [
                    QPoint(10,a),
                    QPoint(100,b),#laro,alto
                    QPoint(100,c),
                    QPoint(30,d),
                    QPoint(25,e),
                    QPoint(20,f),
                    QPoint(10,g)

                ]
                poly = QPolygon(points)
                r=painter.drawPolygon(poly)

                a = a+50
                b = b+50
                c = c+50
                d = d+50
                e = e+50
                f = f+50
                g = g+50

                boxlayout.addWidget(r)
            #boxlayout.addWidget(self.label2)
            self.scrollArea.setWidget(central)
            self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

app = QApplication([])
m  =Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Pero no se  muestra nada dentro del `QScrollArea` espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explicación:**

Parece que desconoces para que sirve un QPolygon, si revisamos la [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpolygon.html):

> The QPolygon class provides a vector of points using integer precision.

Que traducido indica que la clase QPolygon es un vector de puntos donde cada coordenada es un entero. QPolygon no es un elemento visual, asi que lo que pides es imposible tal como preguntas.

Por otro lado el metodo paintEvent sirve para pintar el mismo widget, no sirve para pintar otros widgets. Ademas no debes crear widgets dentro de ese método ya que se llama continuamente.

**Solución:**

Asi que lo pienso que deseas preguntar es : ¿Como dibujar un poligono en un widget que se establezca en el QScrollArea?. Si es asi debes crear un widget donde se pinte usando la información del QPolygon, y luego establecer ese widget en el QScrollArea.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.green, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))

        a, b, c, d, e, f, g = 10, 10, 50, 50, 60, 50, 50
        points = [
            QtCore.QPoint(10, a),
            QtCore.QPoint(100, b),
            QtCore.QPoint(100, c),
            QtCore.QPoint(30, d),
            QtCore.QPoint(25, e),
            QtCore.QPoint(20, f),
            QtCore.QPoint(10, g),
        ]
        poly = QtGui.QPolygon(points)
        for i in range(10):
            painter.drawPolygon(poly)
            poly.translate(0, 50)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(100, 800)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("testUI.ui", self)

        central = Widget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(central)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```